# I am getting error" Static method 'buildBlock' requires that 'UInt' conform to 'View'" when trying to read data from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui

I simply just want to read the data and store it in an int but I can't seem to read the data of any type without having an error. Please let me know if you need any addition information about the project

Code:

```
import FirebaseDatabaseSwift
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

struct InGameView: View {
    var ref: DatabaseReference! = Database.database().reference()
    var refOffset: DatabaseReference! = Database.database().reference().child("")
    
    var body: some View {
        

        refOffset.observe(.value) { DataSnapshot in
            print(DataSnapshot)
        }
    }
 }
```

Database Screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d65Qs.png)

Comment: The top level of the rendering area of a SwiftUI view is for rendering the UI, nothing else. Do the *controller* stuff in `init`, `.task`, `.onAppear` or in a view model

Comment: Move your Firebase observer out of the view, put it in your model.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with FireBase.  `refOffset.observe(.value)` does not return a view, therefore it shouldn't be used in `var body`. You may be able to make it compile by changing it to:

```
var body: some View {

    let _ = refOffset.observe(.value) { DataSnapshot in
        print(DataSnapshot)
    }
}
```

but don't, that is very poor practice. A call like that should be in its own function, and called from an `init()` or `.onAppear()`, or as a result of some state change.